# I need to export a file in fbx, png and zip format

Tags: modeling

I don't know much about this, sorry if my question caused confusion, what I meant is that I want to participate in a contest which asks for a 3D character with fbx, png and zip format but my program does not have png or zip (I don't know much about this) what do I do?

Comment: Hi. This is an English speaking site. Please translate this into English. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean, that you have a model that uses a texture in png format and don't know how to map the texture?